# Overriding the default route / path helper in rails to use something other than the `id` field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I can view any User' object's `show` page in my app using the url

```
/users/:id
# eg. /users/7
```

Instead of using the `id` from my database, I wanted to use a unique hash id that I generate for each user. It looks neater and avoids exposing my sequential DB information

```
/users/kF87sl8H2
```

However I lose the convenience of using the route path helper I was previously using - `user_path(@user)`. I now have to replace it in multiple places with `user_path(id: @user.hash_id)`

Is there a way to keep the old route helper and just pass it my `@user` instance? I assume it involves overriding the path helper somehow?

Also, marginally related - is there a best practice around generating those hash ID's? I was just going to use `SecureRandom.hex`, but I know Google+ uses numbers only and Youtube uses different case letters

e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

Is there a good way to generate those?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
resources :users, param: :hash_id
```

add the `param` to your routes file with `resources` as above with your `model field` and change the `find` method in your controller as below.

```
@user = User.find_by(hash_id: params[:hash_id])
```

[Here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters) is the officail documentation for the same.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do the following to override the route helper method for your User class

```
class User
  def to_param
    hash_id
  end
end
```